go string template won't interpolate variables properly and I can't seem to figure out why
WHERE
  1=1
  {{- if .Params.FromDate }}
    AND datestr >= '{{ ConvertDate .Params.FromDate }}'
  {{- else }}
    AND datestr >= '{{.CurrentDate }}'
  {{- end }}

so here is a snippet from a query template I have, const template = '...'.
I am inserting variables into the .Params.FromDate and .CurrentDate from a separate go file.
However when I execute my function that is supposed to print this template and interpolate these pieces of data it just shows up as an empty string for the else statement '' when I don't include the .Params.FromDate variable, and I don't know why.
When the statement is true and a .Params.FromDate is provided, the data is printed correctly. And when I put .CurrentDate into the true logic it prints out fine, however when the logic is false an empty string is provided and not .CurrentDate which I passed in.
I checked and .CurrentDate is initialized and passed in but it just doesn't print and I can't figure out why.
templateData := map[string]interface{}{
        "Params":      params,
        "CurrentDate": currentDate,
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(&queryBuilder, templateData)
    fmt.Println(queryBuilder.String())

above is how i'm calling it in another go file. tmpl is the string template in the first code block.

What is the error returned from the template's Execute method?

Edit the question to include a [mcve].

@CeriseLimón no error, just produces an empty string. But when {{.CurrentDate}} is put in the spot where '{{ ConvertDate .Params.FromDate }}' is, and the condition is set to True, it is present now. But when it is set to false and it is in its original state, its an empty string.

While I figure it's a bit cumbersome to create a minimal working example, it looks as some context is missing otherwise.  You can also try to create a method like func debug(toInspect ...any) string { debugStr := fmt.Printf("debug: %v\n", toInspect); return ""} and invoke it before the condition with {{ debug .CurrentDate }} to check the real values under the different circumstances.

I would assume it is related to this

Known options:


missingkey: Control the behavior during execution if a map is indexed with a key that is not present in the map.


"missingkey=default" or "missingkey=invalid"
The default behavior: Do nothing and continue execution.
If printed, the result of the index operation is the string
"".


"missingkey=zero"
The operation returns the zero value for the map type's element.


"missingkey=error"
Execution stops immediately with an error.

It sounds like you want to use the option "missingkey=zero":
tmpl.Option("missingkey=zero").Execute(&queryBuilder, templateData)

Alternatively, you can do
{{- if index .Params "FromDate" }}
which should use the "missing key is zero value" by default

(note: seeing the type declaration -- and possibly the values -- for params and the code for ConvertDate would help understanding your issue)
One blind guess: if params is a struct and FromDate is a time.Time (<- as in: not a pointer to a time.Time), I think {{ if .Params.FromDate }} will always be true. Is it possible that you see the effect of your ConvertDate function for a .IsZero() date ?

It looks like you are using plain text templates to generate a SQL query, beware of the consequences (most notably: the possible query injections if you insert values that come from a client's request).
The standard sql drivers all support a way to pass parameters (and handle escaping), so I would advise to use that.

For the scope of templates: it is generally a good idea to have as little logic as possible in your templates; another way to fix your issue could be to run your computation in go, and provide a MinDate value to your template:
//----- code:
dt := params.FromDate
if dt.IsZero() {
    dt = currentDate
}

tmpl.Execute(&queryBuilder, map[string]any{"MinDate": convertDate(dt)}


//----- template:
WHERE datestr >= {{ .MinDate }}

